# Is there any need for the int id in the PUT method code below?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm new to asp.net core and c# but I don't understand why my PUT method declares an id property and tries to bind it with the ID property from my model class. Why can't the action call the ID property directly?

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]

    public async Task<IActionResult> PutPatient(int id, Patient patient)

    {
        if (id != patient.PatientId)

        {

            return BadRequest();

        }
```

Comment: You definitely can, but hey, REST.

Comment: Can you post your alternative?

Comment: Specifying the id in the URL and the body seems a bit redundant. The idea is probably to use the same model for request and response.

Comment: @juunas I guess so. But is there a possible way to do this without the redundancy

Answer (score 2):

I think it might have to do with preventing duplicate record creation. According to the [Microsoft REST API Guidelines](https://github.com/microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md#95-changing-collections) (emphasis added is mine):

> POST requests are not idempotent. This means that two POST requests sent to a collection resource with exactly the same payload MAY lead to multiple items being created in that collection. This is often the case for insert operations on items with a server-side generated id.
>
> For example, the following request:
>
> `POST https://api.contoso.com/v1.0/people`
>
> Would lead to a response indicating the location of the new collection item:
>
> `201 Created
>   Location: https://api.contoso.com/v1.0/people/123`
>
> And once executed again, would likely lead to another resource:
>
> `201 Created
>   Location: https://api.contoso.com/v1.0/people/124`
>
> While a PUT request would require the **indication of the collection item with the corresponding key** instead:
>
> `PUT https://api.contoso.com/v1.0/people/123`

Answer (score 0):

The link below contains a most useful answer to my question.Explains that I'm updating the patient with say id=4 and sending the id value with the URL but the data I'm updating is in the request body. So I need to bind the id in my PUT method to the Id parameter in the model body. hope it makes sense. Thanks guys

https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/webapi/model-binding-model-binder-example